# Strange behaviour when removing element from array of divs (React Hooks)

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-hooks

I am struggling to understand a strange behaviour while deleting an element from an array of divs.
What I want to do is create an array of divs representing a list of purchases. Each purchase has a delete button that must delete only the clicked one. What is happening is that when the delete button is clicked on the purchase x all the elements with indexes greather than x are deleted.

Any help will be appreciated, including syntax advices :)

```
import React, { useState } from "react";


const InvestmentSimulator = () => {

  const [counter, increment] = useState(0);
  const [purchases, setPurchases] = useState([
    <div key={`purchase${counter}`}>Item 0</div>
  ]);

  function addNewPurchase() {
    increment(counter + 1);
    const uniqueId = `purchase${counter}`;

    const newPurchases = [
      ...purchases,
      <div key={uniqueId}>
        <button onClick={() => removePurchase(uniqueId)}>delete</button>
        Item number {uniqueId}
      </div>
    ];

    setPurchases(newPurchases);
  }

  const removePurchase = id => {
    setPurchases(
      purchases.filter(function(purchase) {
        return purchase.key !== `purchase${id}`;
      })
    );
  };

  const purchasesList = (
    <div>
      {purchases.map(purchase => {
        if (purchases.indexOf(purchase) === purchases.length - 1) {
          return (
            <div key={purchases.indexOf(purchase)}>
              {purchase}
              <button onClick={() => addNewPurchase()}>add</button>
            </div>
          );
        }
        return purchase;
      })}
    </div>
  );

  return <div>{purchasesList}</div>;
};
export default InvestmentSimulator;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues with your code, so I'll go through them one at a time:

---

## Don't store JSX in state

State is for storing serializable data, not UI. You can store numbers, booleans, strings, arrays, objects, etc... but don't store components.

---

## Keep your JSX simple

The JSX you are returning is a bit convoluted. You are mapping through `purchases`, but then also returning an `add` button if it is the last purchase. The add button is not related to mapping the purchases, so define it separately:

```
return (
    <div>
        // Map purchases
        {purchases.map(purchase => (
            // The JSX for purchases is defined here, not in state
            <div key={purchase.id}>
                <button onClick={() => removePurchase(purchase.id)}>
                    delete
                </button>
                Item number {purchase.id}
            </div>
        ))}
        // An add button at the end of the list of purchases
        <button onClick={() => addNewPurchase()}>add</button>
    </div>
)
```

Since we should not be storing JSX in state, the return statement is where we turn our state values into JSX.

---

## Don't give confusing names to setter functions.

You have created a state variable `counter`, and named the setter function `increment`. This is misleading - the function `increment` does not increment the counter, it **sets the counter**. If I call `increment(0)`, the count is not incremented, it is set to 0.

Be consistent with naming setter functions. It is the accepted best practice in the React community that the setter function has *the same name as the variable it sets, prefixed with the word "set"*. In other words, your state value is `counter`, so your setter function should be called `setCounter`. That is accurate and descriptive of what the function does:

```
const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0)
```

---

## State is updated asynchronously - don't treat it synchronously

In the `addNewPurchase` function, you have:

```
increment(counter + 1)
const uniqueId = `purchase${counter}`
```

This will not work the way you expect it to. For example:

```
const [myVal, setMyVal] = useState(0)

const updateMyVal = () => {
  console.log(myVal)
  setMyVal(1)     
  console.log(myVal)
}
```

Consider the above example. The first `console.log(myVal)` would log `0` to the console. What do you expect the second `console.log(myVal)` to log? You might expect `1`, but it actually logs `0` also.

State does not update until the function finishes execution and the component re-renders, so the value of `myVal` will never change part way through a function. It remains the same for the whole function.

In your case, you're creating an ID with the *old* value of `counter`.

---

## The component

Here is an updated version of your component:

```
const InvestmentSimulator = () => {
    // Use sensible setter function naming
    const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0)

    // Don't store JSX in state
    const [purchases, setPurchases] = useState([])

    const addNewPurchase = () => {
        setCounter(prev => prev + 1)
        setPurchases(prev => [...prev, { id: `purchase${counter + 1}` }])
    }

    const removePurchase = id => {
        setPurchases(prev => prev.filter(p => p.id !== id))
    }

    // Keep your JSX simple
    return (
        <div>
            {purchases.map(purchase => (
                <div key={purchase.id}>
                    <button onClick={() => removePurchase(purchase.id)}>
                        delete
                    </button>
                    Item number {purchase.id}
                </div>
            ))}
            <button onClick={() => addNewPurchase()}>add</button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

---

## Final thoughts

Even with these changes, the component still requires a bit of a re-design.

For example, it is not good practice to use a counter to create unique IDs. If the counter is reset, items will share the same ID. I expect that each of these items will eventually store more data than just an ID, so give them each a unique ID that is related to the item, not related to its place in a list.

Comment: Solved my problem! The error was being caused because I was storing JSX in state. Thank you for all the advices

Answer (score 0):

Never use indices of an array as key. Check out [this](https://medium.com/@vraa/why-using-an-index-as-key-in-react-is-probably-a-bad-idea-7543de68b17c) article for more information about that. If you want to use index doing something as I did below.

```js
const purchasesList = (
    <div>
      {purchases.map((purchase, i) => {
        const idx = i;
        if (purchases.indexOf(purchase) === purchases.length - 1) {
          return (
            <div key={idx}>
              {purchase}
              <button onClick={() => addNewPurchase()}>add</button>
            </div>
          );
        }
        return purchase;
      })}
    </div>
  );
```